# Install new Yaru theme on Unity Desktop 7

Tags: unity

How can I install Yaru new theme and Saru icon theme on Unity Desktop 7.5?

I tried to install Saru icon theme with:

```
sudo apt install suru-icon-theme
```

but it doesn't work well.

Comment: Why? What exactly is the problem?

Comment: I would like to apply the new ubuntu theme to my Unity Desktop

Comment: That much was clear but what's the issue? Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you expect to happen and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them *in their entirety* in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. Please **[edit]** your post to add information instead of posting a comment. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Answer (score 2):

You have a typo. It's supposed to be ["**Suru**" icon theme](https://snwh.org/suru) instead of "Saru" icon theme.

To install it run

```
sudo apt install suru-icon-theme
```

Comment: Yes, i know ^^' It was a typing mistake. 
I try that, but the launcher does not change and stays with the old icon theme.

Comment: @ddcas Now that sounds like a different question (*doesn't work* vs. *launcher does not change*). Please clarify your actual issue. Adding screenshots may help a lot.